# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when run the project from terminal

Tags: java, jar, noclassdeffounderror

When I run a project from terminal with "java -jar "projectName".jar, I receive this error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. The problem is that my project includes another project as library and the error refer to classes from that library.

I package the project with "package" command from Maven to make a fat-jar.

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
      <executions>
          <execution>
              <id>make-assembly</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                  <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                  <archive>
                      <manifest>
                          <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                      </manifest>
                  </archive>
                  <descriptorRefs>
                      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                  </descriptorRefs>
              </configuration>
           </execution>
       </executions>
  </plugin>
```

When I run the project from Intellij, the project works. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you unpack the fat jar and see if the dependency library is actually included? If not your fat jar build is wrong.

Comment: Check the filename of the jar you a trying to run from terminal. Should be like xxxx-jar-with-dependencies.jar This is the fat jar.